# PHP array and Sum up entities

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$i = 1; 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT fback FROM whatyouthink');

$featured = array();
$count = 1;
while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {   
     $featured[$count] = $a[0];
     $count++; 
}


//I'm passing all the selected records to another script to reformat

require_once __DIR__ . '/../autoload.php';
$sentiment = new \PHPInsight\Sentiment();
foreach ($featured as $string) {

    // calculations:
    $scores = $sentiment->score($string);
    $class = $sentiment->categorise($string);

    // output:
    //echo "String: $string\n";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Dominant: $class, scores: ";
    print_r($scores);
    echo "\n";
    echo "<br/>";

}
```

> This is the output I get after analyzing with the code above.
>
> Dominant: neg, scores: Array ( [neg] => 0.5 [neu] => 0.25 [pos] =>
>   0.25 )
>
> Dominant: pos, scores: Array ( [pos] => 0.5 [neu] => 0.25 [neg] =>
>   0.25 )
>
> Dominant: pos, scores: Array ( [pos] => 0.5 [neu] => 0.25 [neg] =>
>   0.25 )
>
> Dominant: neg, scores: Array ( [neg] => 0.667 [neu] => 0.167 [pos] =>
>   0.167 )
>
> Dominant: neu, scores: Array ( [neu] => 0.333 [neg] => 0.333 [pos] =>
>   0.333 )
>
> Dominant: pos, scores: Array ( [pos] => 0.4 [neg] => 0.4 [neu] => 0.2
>   )

/code to add the sum array element groups (neg, pos, neu)

```
$sumArray = array();

foreach ($scores as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($scores as $id=>$value) {
    $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
  }
}

print_r($sumArray)


?>
```

**The Output:

```
Array ( [pos] => 1.2 [neg] => 1.2 [neu] => 0.6 )**
```

I want my output to be like this adding up the three elements i.e neg, pos,neu:

```
$rating_data = array(
 array('Sentiment', 'sd'),
 array('neg',sum_neg),
 array('pos',sum_pos),
 array('neu',sum_neu),

);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$rating_data = array(
    array('Sentiment', 'sd'),
);
foreach ($sumArray as $k => $v) {
    $rating_data[] = array($k, $v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$rating_data' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: This is parse error, it's __obvious__, please check your codes again for forgotten `;`

Comment: Thank you. Error fixed but the output does not add up the pos, neg and neu the way I want.

Comment: Be kind and describe what you have and what you want.

Comment: I used the following:

$rating_data = array(
    array('Sentiment', 'sd'),
);
foreach ($sumArray as $k => $v) {
    $rating_data[] = array($k, $v);
}

print_r($rating_data);

I got:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Sentiment [1] => sd ) [1] => Array ( [0] => pos [1] => 1.2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => neg [1] => 1.2 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => neu [1] => 0.6 ) )

I want to achieve:

$rating_data = array(
 array('Sentiment', 'sd'),
 array('neg',sum_neg),
 array('pos',sum_pos),
 array('neu',sum_neu),

);